# Movement of smaller links affecting the whole body

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I've solved the problem of [removing the gravity from the gripper model](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18087/problem-with-making-a-floating-gripper-in-gazebo/), but now I have another problem. When I try to move the grippers claws, whole body starts to move, even if it's not specified at the joint. How can I modify the base link, so it stays rigid while the claws open and close, and also, I need the possibility to move it up and down (and possibly, rotate it)? The models code is in the link above. Here is the behavior that I want to get rid of:

[image]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18109/movement-of-smaller-links-affecting-the-whole-body/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Glad to hear you got the gravity to work, and as I mentioned on the other question, the movement of the other links was expected, now you're basically operating in space ;)

Since you need the gripper itself to move, a fixed joint as previously suggested won't be appropriate for you. What I suggest now is that you add a joint for each degree of freedom which you wish to control. So if you need the arm to move up and down, create a prismatic joint with the world. To allow rotation, add a dummy link and then a revolute joint.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on 2017-12-15**:
Setting prismatic joint with the world did work, although when I added the dummy link, the behavior returned, but then I've set the inertia of the dummy link to a high value and it seems that fixed the problem.